# Manually creating poisson / shot noise

Tags: c, poisson, noise-generator

I am trying to understand and create my own poisson noise generator. I am following the code example seen here: https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/plugins/download/Poisson_Noise.java

It produces poisson noise but my understanding is that this type of noise is controlled by photon samples and I do not see that anywhere here. I also don't understand how to control the intensity of the noise.

Here is my version of the code:

```
  double L, p;
  int k, var=0;

  L = exp (-(float)(src(x,y,0)+src(x,y,1)+src(x,y,2))*0.333); // Red, green and blue channels averaged to one intensity (for now)
  k = 0;
  p = 1.0;

  do
    {
      k++;
      p *= ((float)rand () / (double) RAND_MAX);
    }
  while (p >= L);
  var = k - 1;

  pset(x,y,0, var);
  pset(x,y,1, var);
  pset(x,y,2, var);}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: What don't you see? The photon samples? How would you expect to see them in the code?

Comment: I was under the impression that poisson noise works based on an input of photons. This page describes that: http://registry.gimp.org/node/13016 and if you look at the source code there for the poisson noise, it requires an input of number of photons.

Comment: As any mathematical model of a physical process, it is *completely* decoupled from the process itself. When you are calculating a velocity given distance and the time, you are not seeing anything moving in the code, right?

Comment: You're losing me, Eugene - my understanding of some mathematics is... limited. So the code I posted is correct? How does one control the intensity of the noise, for instance?